# How can I see recent votes?

Tags: support, notifications, recent-activity, voting

As far as I can see the "Recent" Answers shows answers that I have made recently (surprise). I notice that some of those answers have votes applied so I go back and look and sometimes see intersting discussions.

Then I notice that my reputation has increased, but not due to anything on my recent answers. So where was it? Has there been intersting discussion and I missed it?

So any way to get a view of recent "votes" no matter how old the question?

Also, I don't understand when I get notified about comments to my comments. Does that happen? Again I want to not miss an interesting conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the little envelope next to your name at the top of the screen:

[envelope http://shog9.com/so_envelope.png](http://shog9.com/so_envelope.png)

Then click the little number next to [Reputation earned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/82511?startdate=2009-08-05&enddate=2009-08-05&tab=reputation#sort-top): [repnum http://shog9.com/so_recentrep.png](http://shog9.com/so_recentrep.png)

That'll take you [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/82511?startdate=2009-08-05&enddate=2009-08-05&tab=reputation#sort-top), where you can see your recent reputation changes.

Responses to your posts can be found by clicking the number next to [Comment responses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/82511?startdate=2009-08-05&enddate=2009-08-05&tab=responses#sort-top), but that does not include comments in reply to your comments (unless they're on one of your posts).

Comment: Shog, your drop shadows make all of your posts look so pretty!

Comment: Or other peoples posts I guess.

Comment: Yes, those are such pretty red X's! ...Maybe I should check again when I'm not behind a proxy.

Comment: @mmyers: your proxy sucks!

Comment: @Shog9: Kyle Cronin said the same thing (worded differently).

Comment: so many cunning SO features, never noticed that envelope!

Comment: red x's are not acceptable.